# Relations among notions of convergence

Tags: probability, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}A_n=0$. Does this imply that $plim_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n=0$, where $plim$ is the probability limit?

Comment: Are $A_n$ supposed to be random variables?  What is a probability limit for real numbers?

Comment: $A_n$ are real numbers.

Comment: A sequence of real numbers is a sequence of random numbers with trivial distribution.

Comment: 1) It is not a good idea ask another question in comments. 2)  Where have you find the notation $plim$ probability limits?

Comment: in the Econometric book Hayashi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Markov's inequality:

$$
P( |A_n-0|> \epsilon) \leq \frac{E(|A_n|)}{\epsilon}=\frac{|A_n|}{\epsilon}
$$
Letting $n\rightarrow \infty$ on both sides proves convergence in probability.

Answer (score 0):

Defenition for probability limit:

> $X_n\to X$ in probability iff $\forall \epsilon>0$ 
>   $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P\{|X_n-X|>\epsilon\} = 0$.

We should concern sequence of random numbers $X_n$ such that $P\{X_n=A_n\}=1$.
As $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n=0$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $n_\epsilon$ such that  $|A_n|<\epsilon$ for any $n>n_\epsilon$ and the same for $X_n$. 
It implies that $P\{|X_n-0|>\epsilon\}=0$ for $n>n_\epsilon$.

So we have that for any $\epsilon>0$ $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P\{|X_n-0|>\epsilon\} = 0$.